# Django template inner for loop works only once

Tags: django, django-templates, nested-loops

**.html**

```
{% for task_in in object_list %}
<time>
  {%for x in data %}
    {%if x.0 is task_in.id %}
       {{x.1|timesince}}&nbsp ago
    {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %}
</time>
{% endfor %}
```

Here the inner for loop executes only once and I don't understand where I went wrong.

Edit: object_list ,data from **listview**

```
class TaskListView(generic.ListView):
    model = task
    template_name = 'property/task_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        prop_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        return task.objects.filter(task_type='property',related_to__contains=[prop_id]).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context =super(TaskListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        prop_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        obj=task.objects.filter(task_type='property',related_to__contains=[prop_id]).order_by('-id')
        obj1=[]
        obj2=[]
        for task_inst in obj:
            date_str=task_inst.date_due
            format_str='%d-%m-%Y'
            date=datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,format_str).date(),
                datetime.datetime.strptime(task_inst.time,"%H:%M").time())
            obj1.append(date)
            obj2.append(task_inst.id)
        obj3=zip(obj2,obj1)
        context.update({'id':self.kwargs['pk'],'data':obj3})
        return context
```

In the output, only one value from the inner for loop gets displayed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Django has no `is` operator in the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, it does, [since Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#templates). In this case, for comparing integers, `{% if x.0 == task_in.id %}` would be better.

Comment: What are the values of `object_list` and `data`? What is the output of the template? Why do you think "the inner for loop executes only once"?

Comment: i tried changing is to ==, but it still executes only once.

Comment: object_list has values from my queryset  and data has the zipped date,time lists.